# Streaming File Request from Browser to FastAPI

Tags: javascript, streaming, fastapi

I'm trying to stream a request to FastAPI's [UploadFile](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#file-parameters-with-uploadfile) from a browser. I've been trying the example shown [here](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/fetch-streaming-requests/).

fastapi

```
@router.put("/file")
def uploadFile(filename:str,files: List[UploadFile]=File(...)):
```

browser

```
let formData = new FormData();
let that=this
let stream=new ReadableStream({
    async start(controller){
        controller.enqueue(that.files[0])
        controller.close()
    }
})
formData.append("files",stream)
axios({
    url: this.$appConfig.file_url,
    method: 'put',
    data: formData,
    params:{'filename':filename},
    headers: {"Authorization":`Bearer ${this.$store.getters.token}`,"Content-Type":"Multipart/form-data"},
})
```

I get the following error:

> "Expected UploadFile, received: <class 'str'>"

Comment: Streaming is more of a concept server -> browser, not browser -> server. You are just making a PUT request, there is nothing streamingly about it I'd say.